# Retrieving Javascript Map values in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

So I got an issue with my first real stab at using maps that I was hoping someone would be so kind as to shed some light on.  Essentially what I have is a table that I am trying to pass values to, and I set up a variable map in order to use the data-* attribute for passing the info with an onclick event.  However I also need to pass some values automatically that come from several if else statements.  Here is what I have so far:

the map itself:

```
var skills = [
["MATH", math],                             //0
["BIOLOGY", bio],                           //1
["MECHANICS", mech],                        //2
["ELECTRONICS", elect],                     //3
["STEALTH", roll(4,40)],                    //4
["NEGOTIATION", roll(2,20)],                //5
["HORSEMANSHIP", horse],                    //6
["MOTORCYCLE", cycle],                      //7
["MARINE_BIO", marBio],                     //8
["BOTANY", botany],                         //9
["COMPUTERS", comp],                        //10
etc...

var advSkills = [
["FORENSICS", foren],                       //0
["TOXICOLOGY", toxic],                      //1
["STRUCTURAL_ENGINEERING", strEng],         //2
["ENCRYPTION", encrypt],                    //3
["OFF_HAND", roll(3,30)],                   //4
["BURST_CONTROL", roll(3,30)],              //5
["FREIGHT_TRUCKS", freight],                //6
["CONSTRUCTION_VEHICLES", conVeh],          //7
["PHARMACOLOGY", pharma],                   //8
["MICRO_BIOLOGY", micBio],                  //9
["PROGRAMMING", program],                   //10
etc...

var skillMap = new Map(skills);
var advSkillMap = new Map(advSkills);
```

With the target area for these values to be passed looking like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text"  id="skill1" value="" readonly /></td>
  <td><input type="text"  id="skillRate1" value="" readonly /></td>
  <td><input type="text"  id="skill2" value="" readonly /></td>
  <td><input type="text"  id="skillRate2" value="" readonly /></td>
  <td><input type="text"  id="skill3" value="" readonly /></td>
  <td><input type="text"  id="skillRate3" value="" readonly /></td>
  <td><input type="text"  id="skill4" value="" readonly /></td>
  <td><input type="text"  id="skillRate4" value="" readonly /></td>
</tr>
```

the if else is set up as such:

```
function background(){
    var background = roll(1,100);
//DOCTOR
    if (background <= 5){

    getSkill(skillMap.get([36]));
    getSkill(["BIOLOGY"]);
    getSkill(["FIRST_AID"]);
    getAdvSkill(["DOCTOR"]);
    //botany && holis || bio && pharma
        return "Doctor";

//CHEMIST
    } else if (background >= 6 && background <= 8){
    getSkill(skillMap.get([36]));
    getSkill(["MATH"]);
    getSkill(["CHEMISTRY"]);
    //botany && holis || bio && toxic
        return "Chemist";
```

and the actual getSkill function is here:

```
var n = 1;
var an = 1;
function getSkill(skillMap(index)){
  do {
    document.getElementById("skill" + n).setAttribute("value", skillMap.get([0]));
    document.getElementById("skillRate" + n).setAttribute("value", skillMap.get([1]);
    n ++;
    break;
  } while (n < 17);
}
```

So my issue is that I cant seem to pass the index of the map item in order to retrieve the secondary indexes as demonstrated with this piece of code:

```
getSkill(skillMap.get([36]));
```

What am I missing here? At first I thought it was just a syntax deal so I got rid of the brackets and flew with just the parenthesis but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Its also probably important to point out that the objective is to pass the values of the map with the string being the skill and the variable being the skillRate

Answer (score 0):

First, skillMap is something like this.

```
{
'MATH': math,
'BIOLOGY': bio,
...
}
```

You can get the value by key, `skillMap['MATH'] -> math`.

Or you can get key array by  `Array.from( skillMap.keys() ) -> ['MATH', 'BIOLOGY', ...]`.
And then you can access value by index of key. `skillMap[Array.from(skillMap.keys())[0]] -> math`.

BUT NOT `skillMap.get([36])`.